# Reusing the bitmap variable after recycle

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have recycled the bitmap variable and when I again tried to use the same variable I have some strange errors with reference to recycle. Any solution to this issue ?

### java code:

image1.recycle();
image1=null;

### LogCat:

```
05-29 11:35:42.139: E/AndroidRuntime(695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@2bbad018
05-29 11:35:42.139: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1038)
05-29 11:35:42.139: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1078)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made.

It seems that the createBitmap functions have the potential to re-use the bitmap that you provided. If that is the case, then you shouldn't recycle the temporary bitmap since your final bitmap is using it. One thing you can do is

```
if(tempBitmap != finalBitmap) {
   tempBitmap.recycle();
}
```

That should only recycle the tempBitmap when it isn't the same as the finalBitmap. At least that seems to be what the documentation is implying.

Answer (score 0):

Once you recycle the bitmap its memory is freed. That's mean that bitmaps data are gone from the memory. If you want to use again the same variable you have to decode the Bitmap againg .

```
if (image1 == null || image1.isRecycled()) {
    image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have check before recycling the bitmap, as like :

```
if (img != null && !img.isRecycled()) 
            {
                img.recycle();
                img = null;
                System.gc(); 
            }
```

Here img is bitmap.

Try this type error is sloved.

Comment: it is clear that the image recycle is well done. but the problem crops when I use the same variable with another bitmap in the same scenario

Comment: idk what's the reason behind this solution in many answers, problem is bitmap is `recycled`, so why to recycle bitmap with checking `!isRecycled()`?